# calling destructor in custom container

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I am designing a custom C++ template container like this:

```
template <class C>
class Container {
public:
    ...
    void clear() {
        // should I call destructor on elements here?
        for (i...)
            array[i].~C(); // ?
    }

    ~Container() {
        delete [] array_;
    }
private:
    C* array_;
};
```

Should I call the destructor on elements manually inside clear()? If I don't, they will be called later when the container is destroyed (since I delete [] array_ in destructor), but this is not the expected behaviour (we expect them to be destroyed right inside clear(), just like std::vector does).
However, if I do call the destructors, that memory remains in place and when I will be adding new elements on top of the old ones (which now are destroyed), the assignment operator will be called on those destroyed elements, and this may result in undefined behavior.
Suppose I have a class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { foo_ = new int; }
    ~Foo() { delete foo_; } // note I don't explicitly set foo_ to nullptr here
    Foo(Foo &&f) {
        f.foo_ = std::exchange(foo_, f.foo_); // standard practice in move constructors
    }
};
```

OK, this may look good so far, but now if I make a

```
Container<Foo> c;
c.add(Foo());
c.clear();
c.add(Foo());
```

when calling clear() the destructor of the initial Foo is called, leaving its foo_ pointer dangling. Next, when adding the second Foo, the temporary R-value is exchanged with the old contents of the destructed object and when the temp will be destroyed, its destructor will try to delete the same dangling pointer again, which will crash.

So, how to correctly clear() a container without leaving room for double deletion?
I also read that its recommended not to set pointers to nullptr in destructor in order not to not hide potential dangling pointer problems.

I'm a little confused about how to approach this.

EDIT:-------------------

There seems to be no compromise-free approach for a template container.
So far I see these options, as others pointed out:

1. completely delete the underlying array in clear(); this would be
   safe but not performant. I cannot use this option however since I'm
   implementing a lock-free multi-threaded container.
2. instead of calling the destructor on elements in clear(), I would call the default constructor instead: array[i] = C(); This seems
   like the best solution so far - except it still implies an extra
   default construction.
3. use placement new in add() - this seems to work for copy-construction. **However, move-construction into an uninitialized object still seems problematic because most move constructors are implemented with exchanges between pointers - this would leave the source object (moved from) invalid.**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you define Container<T>::add? Do you have a preallocated uninitialized cells, or do you reallocate the whole array each time?

Comment: @Necto, I have a preallocated array of uninitialized cells, and use copy construction or move construction (depending on how add is called). It's like std::vector if I'm not missing something

Comment: How do you allocate that array?

Comment: array = new C[capacity];
so array contains objects of type C, which is the trick. When they become destructed, they are still there and their = operator or copy/move constructors still get called

Comment: @BogdanIonitza `new` does _not_ allocate uninitialised elements. I gues you meant _default-constructed_. The two are diametrically opposed concepts. I get what you're trying to say, but we all know how careful we need to be with terminology in C++!

Comment: @underscore_d, disagreed. `new` in general case does both: allocates and calls a constructor.

Comment: @Necto I'm not sure you actually read my comment at all. How does "`new` does _not_ allocate uninitialised elements" conflict with what you've said? More to the point, I specifically said "_default-constructed_" wrt the example given by the OP. You're attempting to correct me by telling me the same thing I've already said.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, you are correct. I meant default-constructed. The problem really is in trying to construct a new object on top of a destroyed one, which could be done either by placement new (in which case you must pass exactly the parameters that the constructor is expecting - which may be impossible in a templatized scenario) or by copy/move construction - which is easy with templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specified in the comments, in the unassigned cells you have objects constructed by the default constructor (`T()`). That may be bad for performance, but certainly preserves the object abstraction.
Instead of deleting the entries, just replace them with the ones constructed by the default constructor:

```
template <class C>
class Container {
public:
    ...
    void clear() {
        for (i...)
            array_[i] = C();
    }

    ~Container() {
        delete [] array_;
    }
private:
    C* array_;
};
```

### Alternative implementation

On the other hand, I would propose a more performant approach, although it breaks the nice C++ abstraction. You could allocate the memory without invoking the unnecessary default constructor:

```
template <class C>
class Container {
public:
    Container(int n) {
        array_ = (C*)malloc(sizeof(C)*n);
        size_ = 0;
    }

    ...

    void clear() {
        for (... i < size_ ...)
            array_[i].~C();
        size_ = 0;
    }

    ~Container() {
        clear();
        free(array_);
    }
private:
    C* array_;
    int size_;
};
```

Here you do call destructors on all the initialized elements, but you do not call it second time, because you keep track of which are initialized, which are not.

Comment: "uninitialised" and "constructed by the default constructor" are diametrically opposed concepts. I get what you're trying to say, but we all know how careful we need to be with terminology in C++!

Comment: @underscore_d, thank you, I replaced the term with "unassigned".

Comment: Great answer @Necto! Replacing them with default-constructed objects will definitely work, altough it wouldn't be very performance friendly.

The second way, with using manually allocated memory wouldn't be any different from the first when add()-ing objects (by move or copy) since we still have the problem of the destructor being called automatically when copying into the destination (or when destroying the moved-from source object)

Comment: @BogdanIonitza, the second approach is substantially different in `add`ing: use a [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to invoke a copy constructor directly in the uninitialized cell. `new (array_+size_) C(ref)`

Comment: @Necto, but calling the copy-constructor on an uninitialized object (as would be the case with placement new over manually allocated memory) could crash (because the destructor is not aumatically called on the destination before an assignment): say you have a manually allocated ptr in the constructor and in the copy constructor you need to free it before taking on the new value, else it would leak)

Comment: @BogdanIonitza, you are talking about the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment). A [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) works on uninitialized objects, and must not assume anything about the object being constructed.

Comment: correct @Necto, stupid confusion on my side. I guess this kind of solves all my problems, by being able to use placement new with copy constructor.

Comment: @BogdanIonitza, please do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @Necto I did, however I still think move-construction would be problematic - see the bold section edit on the initial question

Comment: @BogdanIonitza, I don see any trouble there. Please formulate another question to address placement new/copy constructor/assignment operator/move constructor differences

Comment: To use this "alternative approach" cleanly, you would need to separately track both the number of initialised objects and the allocated size.   Also, no need to use `malloc()` - it could be done with `::operator new()` (or a class-specific `operator new()`) - a function which allocates raw memory without initialising it

Answer (score 3):

The `delete [] array_` will invoke the destructor for each element of `array_` (assuming `C` is a type with a destructor).

Invoking a destructor twice on any given object gives undefined behaviour.

This means your `clear()` member function should not directly invoke destructors for the array elements.

If you insist on having a separate `clear()` function, which does not interfere with working of the destructor, simply implement it as

```
void clear()
{
    delete [] array_;
    array = nullptr;       //  NULL or 0 before C++11
}
```

This won't interfere with the destructor since operator `delete` has no effect if acting on a NULL pointer.

Comment: OK, this would work and doesn't suffer from any of the drawbacks of my initial proposals. However it would incur a performance penalty since the array must be reallocated after every clear().
From what i managed to decrypt from the STL headers, the std::vector doesn't delete its underlying array on clear(), just calls destructors which would be susceptible to the same problem I described in the post

Comment: @BogdanIonitza I guess, the STL also does not `delete [] array`, it frees the memory without invoking the destructors, because it may very well be uninitialized.

Comment: STL implementations are meant to use _placement new_ idiom. You also can do it.